# Excel vba userform textbox controls

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multipage user form and I can't get the data that gets updated in the form  to update in excel. The code I have only updates Row 2 no matter which row I edit in the form. Here is the code I am using.

```
Dim currentrow As Long

Private Sub btnClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub frmDrgReg_Initialize()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets(1)
        Call resetForm

        currentrow = 2
        Me.txtRev = Cells(currentrow, 10)
        Me.txtScale = Cells(currentrow, 11)
        Me.txtProjDesc = Cells(currentrow, 12)
       Me.txtFacDesc = Cells(currentrow, 13)
       Me.txtItemDesc = Cells(currentrow, 14)
       Me.txtType = Cells(currentrow, 15)


End Sub

Private Sub btnApply_Click()
       answer = MsgBox("you are about to apply the changes", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Apply Changes")
       If answer = vbYes Then
       currentrow = 2
       Cells(currentrow, 10) = Me.txtRev.Text
       Cells(currentrow, 11) = Me.txtScale.Text
       Cells(currentrow, 12) = txtProjDesc.Text
       Cells(currentrow, 13) = txtFacDesc.Text
       Cells(currentrow, 14) = txtItemDesc.Text
       Cells(currentrow, 15) = txtType.Text
       End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
        Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Sheets(1).Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Me.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
        For i = 2 To LastRow
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(1).Cells(i, "H").Value
        Next i
        End If

End Sub
```

In the `Sub btnApply_Click()` how can I use a For Each loop similar to the one I have used in my resetForm sub

```
Public Sub resetForm()
        Dim ctl As Control
        For Each ctl In frmDrgReg.Controls
                If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
                        ctl Value = ""
                End If
        Next ctl

        frmDrgReg.ComboBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that what you are telling it to? `currentrow = 2`? If you want to add data to the last row then you need to calculate that. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to find the last row. I want to update the row data that I have selected from the ComboBox1

Comment: Then assign that value to `currentrow`? I don't see that you try to do that, anywhere.

Comment: Where do I assign currentrow? In which Sub?